# Slice an array based on matching conditions with $lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm discovering Mongodb and its queries with pipelines and I'm struggling on a case.

I'm looking for each **pathsList** document where I can find a path from a position B to a position C

- Inputs: 10 and 12
- Output: [pathsList] (I expect only 1 result in this example, but more likely an array later on)

Let's say I have the 2 following **pathsList** documents from pathsListsCollection, they have an array of **path** documents

```
-------------
pathsList = {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    pathIds: [path1Id, path2Id, path3Id]
}
-------------
path1 = {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    positionStart: 8,
    positionFinal: 10,
    index:0
}
-------------
path2 = {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    positionStart: 10,
    positionFinal: 12,
    index:1
}
-------------
path3 = {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    positionStart: 12,
    positionFinal: 14,
    index:2
}
-------------

-------------
pathsList = {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    pathIds: [path4Id, path5Id, path6Id]
}
-------------
path4 = {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    positionStart: 14,
    positionFinal: 12,
    index:0
}
-------------
path5 = {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    positionStart: 12,
    positionFinal: 10,
    index:1
}
-------------
path6 = {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    positionStart: 10,
    positionFinal: 8,
    index:2
}
-------------
```

So far I've done something like this:

```
pathsListCollection.aggregate([
    {
    $lookup:{
        from: "pathsCollection",
        localField: "pathIds",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: paths
        }
    },
    {
        $match:{
            paths.positionStart : 10 // first input value
        }
    },
    {
        $match:{
            paths.positionFinal : 12  // second input value
        }
    },
])
```

Doing this I get the 2 pathsList docs.

Now, how can I change this aggregate to find only the one having a positionStart = 10 and positionFinal = 12 in that specific order
How can try to validate the second expression only if the first one already has been validate?

I've looked into $slice trying to slice the paths array after the first $match, and continue the query with the rest of it, but couldn't find any revelent syntax to do it.

ie: working with the first pathsList, I reach the first $match with a **paths array** like that :

```
[{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    positionStart: 8,
    positionFinal: 10,
    index:0
},
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    positionStart: 10,     // first $match here
    positionFinal: 12,
    index:1
},
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    positionStart: 12,
    positionFinal: 14,
    index:2
}]
```

and I want to do the next $match on an array like that :

```
[{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    positionStart: 10,
    positionFinal: 12,    // second $match has to start from this elem of the array
    index:1
},
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    positionStart: 12,
    positionFinal: 14,
    index:2
}]
```

Is it possible to do that?
would it be easier to query pathsCollection rather than pathsListsCollection in first place?

However, I'm open to any different approach or thoughs which could help me to solve that problem
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking that given two input values (let's call them "A" and "B" ) to find the "pathsCollection" items which have "either" the matching "positionStart" OR "positionFinal" to the supplied values? And then possibly retrieve the "related" pathsList, which contains the matching items?

Comment: yes, I receive A and B
A has to match with a positionStart
and 
B has to match with a positionFinal (if this positionFinal is a property of an element having an index greater or equal than the element of the previous match)
does it make sense ?

Comment: So the order of the "slice" would be `B,A` then. Correct? Is there anything else that determines the "parent" here? Or is it just the particular parent that includes "both" items?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the slice, basically I want to get rid of all elements of the current paths array with an index lower than the matching element with A. 
Otherwise nothing else from the parent, I just go through all pathsList and process on their [paths array]

Comment: Do you think you could edit your question and include some actual values in there as well as what you are supplying as a value to query on which determines what matches. `posA,posB` is too abstract as compared to `1,2,3`. Understand? I'm sensing from the wording that english is not a first language, therefore an "example" would be better. I think I understand, but you are almost contradicting every clarification I ask for. So "real values" would help to make it clear.

Comment: is it better? 
If you look at the second pathsList object (with [path4Id, path5Id, path6Id]), with the current query I'll receive this object because I have 10 as  positionStart in path6 and 12 as positionFinal in path4. This is the kind of results I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting this then you want to "slice" based on a given matching `positionStart` and and `positionFinish` here.

### Optimal Case

It would in fact be better for performance if you indeed start the query on the `"pathsCollection"` instead, because that is where you are actually going to match the items. So the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) there should be done "first" and using an [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) expression to "slice" across the range:

Then with the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) you would then only return the `"pathsListCollection"` items, formatted with the "sliced" array:

On a minimal sample of your data, going from "start" `10` to "finish" `12` would be:

```
db.getCollection('pathsCollection').aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "positionStart": { "$gte": 10, "$lte": 12 },
    "positionFinal": { "$gte": 10, "$lte": 12 }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "pathsListCollection",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "pathIds",
    "as": "pathsList"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$pathsList" },
  { "$addFields": {
    "pathsList.pathIds": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$pathsList.pathIds",
        "as": "p",
        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$p" ] }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$pathsList.pathIds" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$pathsList._id",
    "pathIds": {
      "$push": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "positionStart": "$positionStart",
        "positionFinal": "$positionFinal",
        "index": "$index"  
      }  
    }  
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$and": [
          { "$eq": [
            { "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$pathIds.positionStart",
              0 
            ]},
            10
          ]},
          { "$eq": [
            { "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$pathIds.positionFinal",
              -1
            ]},
            12
          ]}  
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"  
    }  
  }}
])
```

Would produce:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595db5d8f5f11516540d1185"),
    "pathIds" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("595db4c7f5f11516540d1183"),
            "positionStart" : 10.0,
            "positionFinal" : 12.0,
            "index" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}
```

And with reducing the "range" to "start" `10` and "finish" `14`, that would be :

```
db.getCollection('pathsCollection').aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "positionStart": { "$gte": 10, "$lte": 14 },
    "positionFinal": { "$gte": 10, "$lte": 14 }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "pathsListCollection",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "pathIds",
    "as": "pathsList"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$pathsList" },
  { "$addFields": {
    "pathsList.pathIds": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$pathsList.pathIds",
        "as": "p",
        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$p" ] }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$pathsList.pathIds" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$pathsList._id",
    "pathIds": {
      "$push": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "positionStart": "$positionStart",
        "positionFinal": "$positionFinal",
        "index": "$index"  
      }  
    }  
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$and": [
          { "$eq": [
            { "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$pathIds.positionStart",
              0 
            ]},
            10
          ]},
          { "$eq": [
            { "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$pathIds.positionFinal",
              -1
            ]},
            14
          ]}  
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"  
    }  
  }}
])
```

Producing:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595db5d8f5f11516540d1185"),
    "pathIds" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("595db4c7f5f11516540d1183"),
            "positionStart" : 10.0,
            "positionFinal" : 12.0,
            "index" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("595db4c7f5f11516540d1184"),
            "positionStart" : 12.0,
            "positionFinal" : 14.0,
            "index" : 2.0
        }
    ]
}
```

---

### Reverse Case

It might look a bit shorter in syntax, but it's probably not the best performing option given that you cannot "query" the `"pathsCollection"` in the reverse case until the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is actually performed:

```
db.pathsListCollection.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "pathsCollection",
    "localField": "pathIds",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "pathIds"    
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$pathIds" },
  { "$match": {
    "pathIds.positionStart": { "$gte": 10, "$lte": 14 },
    "pathIds.positionFinal": { "$gte": 10, "$lte": 14 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "pathIds": { "$push": "$pathIds" }    
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$and": [
          { "$eq": [
            { "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$pathIds.positionStart",
              0 
            ]},
            10
          ]},
          { "$eq": [
            { "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$pathIds.positionFinal",
              -1
            ]},
            14
          ]}  
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"  
    }  
  }}
])
```

That is the most optimal form of the "reverse case" given on how MongoDB actually issues the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) when applied to the server, which can be seen in the "explain" output:

```
    {
        "$lookup" : {
            "from" : "pathsCollection",
            "as" : "pathIds",
            "localField" : "pathIds",
            "foreignField" : "_id",
            "unwinding" : {
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
            },
            "matching" : {
                "$and" : [ 
                    {
                        "positionStart" : {
                            "$gte" : 10.0
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "positionStart" : {
                            "$lte" : 14.0
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "positionFinal" : {
                            "$gte" : 10.0
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "positionFinal" : {
                            "$lte" : 14.0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$group" : {
```

Showing there that the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) have "magically" disappeared. They now of course have been "rolled-up" into the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) so that when the related data is queried, you actually get **only** those results that matched the given condition.

The "non-optimal" approach would be to [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) instead. But in fact **ALL** results from the related collection are returned, and then only removed once the "full" array was already present:

```
db.pathsListCollection.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "pathsCollection",
    "localField": "pathIds",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "pathIds"    
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "pathIds": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$pathIds",
        "as": "p",
        "cond": {
          "$and": [
            { "$gte": [ "$$p.positionStart", 10 ] },
            { "$lte": [ "$$p.positionStart", 14 ] },            
            { "$gte": [ "$$p.positionFinal", 10 ] },
            { "$lte": [ "$$p.positionFinal", 14 ] },            
          ]
        }
      } 
    }  
  }},
  { "$match": {
    "pathIds": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "positionStart": { "$gte": 10, "$lte": 14 },
        "positionFinal": { "$gte": 10, "$lte": 14 }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$and": [
          { "$eq": [
            { "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$pathIds.positionStart",
              0 
            ]},
            10
          ]},
          { "$eq": [
            { "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$pathIds.positionFinal",
              -1
            ]},
            14
          ]}  
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"  
    }  
  }}
])
```

Also noting that you still need to [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) or [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) given that the resulting array entries still meet the conditions in this case, and that the array was not in fact "empty" as a result of the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/).

---

### Samples used

**pathsCollection**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595db4c7f5f11516540d1182"),
    "positionStart" : 8.0,
    "positionFinal" : 10.0,
    "index" : 0.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595db4c7f5f11516540d1183"),
    "positionStart" : 10.0,
    "positionFinal" : 12.0,
    "index" : 1.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595db4c7f5f11516540d1184"),
    "positionStart" : 12.0,
    "positionFinal" : 14.0,
    "index" : 2.0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595db616f5f11516540d1186"),
    "positionStart" : 14.0,
    "positionFinal" : 12.0,
    "index" : 0.0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595db616f5f11516540d1187"),
    "positionStart" : 12.0,
    "positionFinal" : 10.0,
    "index" : 1.0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595db616f5f11516540d1188"),
    "positionStart" : 10.0,
    "positionFinal" : 8.0,
    "index" : 2.0
}
```

**pathsListCollection**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595db5d8f5f11516540d1185"),
    "pathIds" : [ 
        ObjectId("595db4c7f5f11516540d1182"), 
        ObjectId("595db4c7f5f11516540d1183"), 
        ObjectId("595db4c7f5f11516540d1184")
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595db62df5f11516540d1189"),
    "pathIds" : [ 
        ObjectId("595db616f5f11516540d1186"), 
        ObjectId("595db616f5f11516540d1187"), 
        ObjectId("595db616f5f11516540d1188")
    ]
}
```

Comment: @FrédéricDelage Sure. But that's why I include the data as used and the actual outputs from the aggregation pipelines as used. It's a fairly simple premise that the "selection" is actually done in the first `$match` stage. Then we just do all the rest to "join" and reconstruct the related collection into the "sliced" form.

Comment: Hi, so I've tested it (once again thanks for this help), it's not exactly what I wanted but it's quite close I reckon, I should be able to workout what is missing and post it.
The missing bit is a way to figure out the 'direction' of a pathsList. 
In your sample, the paths are going from 1.0 to 4.0, but I can have the same pathsList going from 4.0 to 1.0 
(and so the first path of the list will have "positionStart" : 4.0, "positionFinal" : 3.0, "index" : 0.0)

Comment: @FrédéricDelage It's not clear what you mean there, and it seems certainly different to what your question actually asks. The "slice" as it were, in all cases is looking in the "children" to run "fromValue" and then "toValue". I'm not sure if you are asking to "do that in reverse?" with "descending values?" It's not really clear without a case to see, nor does it really even look like the same question, and is possibly a different question. So perhaps you should [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) where you can clearly state what the "different" behavior actually is.

Comment: @FrédéricDelage But as I see it, "This is the answer to the question you actually asked here". Changing your question once an answer has addressed what it actually asked is not really an accepted practice here. If you have different conditions to those that were presented in the original question, then it is best to "Ask a new Question", as already noted.

Comment: Ok I got it. 
However reusing the two pathsList samples mentioned in the **question** with the same inputs (10 and 12), I just expect a result like this :
{
    _id: ObjectId("id of the first pathsList"),
    pathIds:  [{ _id: ObjectId("id of path2"),
                    positionStart: 10,
                    positionFinal: 12,
                    index:}]
}

Comment: @FrédéricDelage In all fairness I did need to prompt you for that input, as well as the bulk of the answer was actually written before you included that information (hence the state of the sample in the answer). It may be as simple as reversing the the case with additional `$or` arguments. But I'd have to take a much closer look to be certain. If there's a clear case then I'll update when I can.

Comment: @FrédéricDelage I think I owe you an apology there. I read the question through again and included all the data you supplied. This led me to 1. Correct the range selection. 2. Add a `$redact` at the end of the pipeline to exclude "range matches" that went in the "reverse direction". Which I "think" is what you are actually saying. At least that's my best interpretation of the question. If you actually wanted "both directions" then removing the `$redact` would do that as well.

Comment: Hi Neil, great job (and nice understanding) it's exactly what I meant by 'direction'. It works fine with the $redact.

Comment: @FrédéricDelage Technically speaking that does not even "need" to be a `$redact`. You can simply `$match` on the first array position being equal to the "first argument" given, which would also indicate "direction". As in `{ "$match": { "pathIds.0.positionStart": 10 } }` in this example. Really just showing checking the "last index" as an example. But you should be able to safely presume as well.